# Adding key/legend to histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have not been able to add a legend to my histogram, created using matplotlib.pyplot.
Would appreciate some help/advice.

The below dataset is junk data, but is an accurate example of the situation, two datasets, both in the same dataframe, seperated by a filter on a column.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math
import pyodbc
import re


data = [{ 'uid':1,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':24},
        { 'uid':2,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':12},
        { 'uid':3,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':23},
        { 'uid':4,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':12},
        { 'uid':1,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':24},
        { 'uid':2,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':12},
        { 'uid':3,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':23},
        { 'uid':4,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':12},
        { 'uid':1,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':24},
        { 'uid':2,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':12},
        { 'uid':3,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':23},
        { 'uid':4,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':12},
        { 'uid':1,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':24},
        { 'uid':2,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':12},
        { 'uid':3,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':23},
        { 'uid':4,'Region':'nebraska', 'metric1':12},
        { 'uid':29,'Region':'colorado', 'metric1':14},
        { 'uid':30,'Region':'colorado', 'metric1':45},
        { 'uid':30,'Region':'colorado', 'metric1':45},
        { 'uid':30,'Region':'colorado', 'metric1':45},
        { 'uid':31,'Region':'colorado', 'metric1':65},
        { 'uid':32,'Region':'colorado', 'metric1':50}
        ]

testDataset = pd.DataFrame(data)

b = np.arange(0,100, 50)


plt.hist(testDataset[testDataset['Region'] == 'nebraska']['metric1'], b,color = 'red')   
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 100, 10))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 100, 10))
plt.grid(zorder=0)


plt.hist(testDataset[testDataset['Region'] == 'colorado']['metric1'], b,color = 'blue')   

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply add a `label` argument to your `hist` calls:

```
plt.hist(testDataset[testDataset['Region'] == 'nebraska']['metric1'], b,
         color = 'red', label='Nebraska')
plt.hist(testDataset[testDataset['Region'] == 'colorado']['metric1'], b,
         color = 'blue', label='Colorado')
```

and call `plt.legend()` before `plt.show()`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are just looking for `plt.legend()`

For example:

```
plt.legend(['Red', 'Blue'])
```